# Blogger Api v1.0 deprecated

Tags: python, api, blogger

Blogger deprecated the API(v1.0) I was using to post on blogger. The new API does not have a developer's Guide for Python(or doesn't support it). So I was wondering if there is a way to keep posting to blogger using Python.

API info: https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/1.0/developers_guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the new API [Blogger API v3.0](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/index)

You can simply use the http request modules for creating, retrieving your blogger posts, The new Blogger API v3.0 supports REST web service which can help you to perform all the operations that you would do with the Blogger API(v1.0)

Here are some useful links for your reference:

- [Using REST API](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/getting_started#REST)
- [Adding a post](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#AddingAPost)
- [PyDoc reference for the Blogger API](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/blogger/v3/python/latest/)
- [Developer's guide for the Google API Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/)

Hope the above information helps you!